# Symfony PDOException could not find driver

Tags: symfony, pdo, driver

I have a problem with symfony2.3, today I have this error message : "PDoException could not find driver" while yesterday everything worked perfectly.

When I run this command line : php app/check.php All is ok :

```
 OK       PDO should be installed
 OK       PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: sqlite)
```

In my file parameters.yml all is correctly.

I do not understand why it worked yesterday and today I have this error.

Best regards,

Comment: Can you show us your `parameters.yml` (changing the sensitive information). You are missing the driver you have setup in this file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, verify your **php.ini** file: the extensions (*php_pdo_pgsql* or *php_pdo_mysql*) and *php_pdo* must be enabled. Make sure you apply this changes on php.ini file that your **symfony project** is using, check this on *localhost/path_to_your_project/web/config.php*. You know if this extensions are enabled executing the function *phpinfo()*.

This **command** is also helpfull: *php -m*. It lists on console all the php modules that are loaded.

Tip: check out you **Apache error log**, there could be something wrong with the load of your extensions. This file is located according to your server configuration.